# How to configure chart.js line chart with very low minimum height, and only 0 and 1 (no decimals) as ticks on the y-axis

Tags: layout, chart.js, linechart

[image]

I'm trying to tailor the chart above to take up as little vertical space as possible. It is a line chart showing binary data (1 or 0 for door open or closed), but it seems to force me to have the decimal ticks between the two values, even thought every point's y-axis value is 1 or 0 as integers. Ideally it would be no taller than the width of the y-axis label.

Is this possible? I've tried various things to do with the container, removing y-axis ticks etc, but I'm struggling to get it more compact than this.

UPDATE:

I've managed to get rid of the decimal ticks with config from [these docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#step-size). Still no luck on the height...is there an undocumented minimum or something?

Answer (score 0):

Per this question, the answer is to set a fixed height on the chart canvas.

[Fix the height of Y-Axis of Bar chart in chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41694661/fix-the-height-of-y-axis-of-bar-chart-in-chart-js)